# Prevent a onchecked event in CheckBox while scrolling it in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, scroll, listbox

I have a list of CheckBox in a ListBox, and the ListBox can scroll, but every time I move up or down in the ListBox to see the other CheckBoxes the Checked event fires. Is there any way to prevent it? I just wanted that event to be fired when the IsChecked is changed!

```
<ListBox Margin="0,5,0,0" Grid.Column="1" Background="Transparent" 
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
             SelectionMode="Single" Name="lbPermission" BorderThickness="0"
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsEditable, Mode=OneWay, 
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Expander}}}" 
                              Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}" Content="{Binding Id}" 
                              Checked="CheckedHandler" Unchecked="CheckedHandler" >
                        <CheckBox.IsChecked>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource EnumConverter}" 
                                           Mode="OneWay">
                                <Binding Path="Id" />
                                <Binding Path="CurrentAccessList" 
                                         RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Expander}}" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </CheckBox.IsChecked>
                    </CheckBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

I tried to make it work with TowWay, or using PropertyChanged, but it didn't.

Here is the code for the event:

```
private void CheckedHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(OnDataModifiedEvent));
    }
```

Here is the code for the Converter:

```
public object Convert(object[] value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            // The second value in the MultiBinding should be LaborAccountAccessList
            if ((value[1] as List<LaborAccountAccessList>) != null)
            {
                if (((IList)value[1]).Count > 0)
                    return (((List<LaborAccountAccessList>)value[1]).FirstOrDefault(x => x.PermissionId == value[0].ToString().ToLower()) != null) ?
                        !((List<LaborAccountAccessList>)value[1]).FirstOrDefault(x => x.PermissionId == value[0].ToString().ToLower()).IsObselete : false;
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ErrorLibrary.Instance.ErrorQueueContext.PrintError(String.Format("Unable bind the data to checkbox. Error={0}", e.ToString()));
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The DataContex is just a List of a class which has an Id, and Description as property. It is as simple as:

```
lbPermission.ItemsSource = PermissionList;
```

It works this way that, there is a list of items that I put it in the DataTemplate to create those CheckBoxes, and then CheckBoxes with the use of Converter checking(with the CurrentAccessList) if that specific item IsChecked or not. The CurrentAccessList is a list came from DataBase.

CurrentAccessList has a bool property.

Thanks.

Comment: There is not enough code to reproduce the issue. Please update the question.

Comment: What do you want me to add?

Comment: The Class you are using as DataContext and the EnumConverter implementation. Also could you explain why you need to pass something called CurrentAccessList from the expander to the converter? I'd like to help you, but first I need to reproduce the issue. So I need [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I added as much as I could. I hope it helps.

Comment: I think this line - `<Binding Path="CurrentAccessList" 
                                         RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Expander}}" />` is giving you a binding error in the Output window. Is that so?

Comment: I don't have any errors. The problem is the CheckBoxes are in a ListBox. When I scroll down or up the CheckedHandler calls, and I don't know why, and that creates a problem somewhere else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150957/discussion-between-yevgeniy-and-amir).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the issue because of virtualization.
To avoid this behavior you can add:

```
ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
```

to your listbox.

But the real problem is in your Enum converter.
Virtualization forces the converter to execute when you are scrolling.
And for some reason it returns different values.
That is why handler is being called.